# django_registration urls and routing confusion

Tags: django, django-urls, django-registration

I am new to Django and so I am learning how it works, I got a pretty decent web app stood up and I was playing around with the django_registration plugin.  The thing that confused me is that the templates live in the root site /registration and I can access them from URLs like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">
```

So I thought I could do that for everything in registration but it was not so, as this doesn't work:

```
<a href="{% url 'registration_login' %}">
```

Confused what it is about one that works, and not the other (I sort of come from a rails background and I could see the routes there) this one I am having trouble learning, this was after going through why some urls in my app use a mysite:polls etc with the semi colon (that I think I get)
just confused on the ones that don't live under an app namespace so to speak.

Or should registration_login of worked and I really just did something wrong on the template setup or the urls.py or something?  Just trying to get some background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Just saw it was the `login` url that was giving you the problem. I'll leave the other section about registration_register up for future reference in case it happens to be useful.

The url for the login is located [here](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/auth_urls.py) and is named `auth_login`

`registration_register` bit:

Did you set `INCLUDE_REGISTER_URL` to False in your settings.py file?

Check the source for the urls located [here](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/default/urls.py) and you'll see the following snippet

```
if getattr(settings, 'INCLUDE_REGISTER_URL', True): #Defaults to True
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^register/$',
            RegistrationView.as_view(),
            name='registration_register'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Django, when you use something like {% url 'registration_login' %}, you're referring to the route in the urls file for the given app. If the url route has name=registration_login, this works fine.

So, you mentioned that it's how you access the templates, but it's really just how you specify the route in the URL, not the template. The route then specifies which view to load, which then sets the template HTMl file that will be used.

So, in the above example, you'd need to look at that app's URL file (or the docs) to see what name they gave the route to use {% url %}. If no name is given, you'd just need to use the actual url "/login/" (or whatever it would be) just as you would in any other anchor tag.

I'm not sure which django_registration app you're using, but Django has one that comes with it: django.contrib.auth which you can use. The urls file for it, you'll find that the login URLs route is named "login", so you could use {% url "login" %}.

Take a look at the docs for this for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

Oh, and for your question about the namespace referenced in some cases, (ie, mysite:polls): this is something set in the urls file with app_name. So, if the polls app has app_name=polls in the urls.py, you could then say {% url 'polls:vote' %} for example. It's good to use if you are using many apps, which is almost always the case in a full Django site.

The {% url %} template tag is good to use because you wouldn't have to change your links throughout your site if your urls changed. However, like I mentioned above, you could always reference the url directly like you would in a standard HTML anchor href. You don't have to use {% url %}

For more info on that, check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/